# How to sort array of dictionaries by date using sort descriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of dictionaries where dictionary is like this.

```
Rows = (
    "<DriverRowRecord: 0x7f8de3a240d0>",
    "<DriverRowRecord: 0x7f8de3a18790>"
);
Sections = "<DriverSectionRecord: 0x7f8de3a2c5a0>";
```

Here `DriverRowRecord` and `DriverSectionRecord` are separate classes. In `DriverSectionRecord` I have a `date` property.

```
@interface DriverSectionRecord : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSDate *date;
@end
```

Now I want to sort the array based on `DriverSectionRecord`'s `date` property. If the dictionary contains the `date` key I sort it like this.

```
  NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
  NSArray *Ascendingorder = [Array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

However, it doesn't work as `date` is a property of `DriverSectionRecord`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to sort `Rows` based on a single `DriverSectionRecord` property?  What?

Comment: `Sections.date`? (if "Sections" is really the key for the `DriverSectionRecord` value, case sensitive.)

Comment: In my array of dictionaries, Each dictionary contains  "DriverSectionRecord" which has date. I want to sort based on that date. The Important thing is I don't have a "date" key in my dictionary.

Comment: @Larme, Wow, "Sections.date" is wrkng. Im thinking like "Sections.DriverSectionRecord.date". Any way can you explain me background process how it worked. I mean Even though Sections Directly don't have date property.

Comment: KVC/`valueForKeyPath:` related (It's "KVC" in fact the real key-word behind that, but `valueForKeyPath:` may give you sample results). That what you'll get if you look at the documentation of `initWitKey:ascending:` reading the `key` parameter.

Comment: @Larme Can I acres that date property like "Sections.date".I mean will my date is printed for this code.    NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"Sections.date"]);

Comment: @sivakrishna: You can't use `objectForKey:` because there is no object by that key, however, you can do `valueForKeyPath:` instead. A KVC key (or KVC keypath) is different to a dictionary's key.

Comment: @dreamlax Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Sections.date" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
 NSArray *Ascendingorder = [Array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

I got he solution from above comments. Thanks to all for such a great clarification.